# How to pass objects between two activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I want to pass an object from Activity B to Activity A.

Scenario:
- Activity A calls Activity B
- User selects item in Activity B
- Activity B passes an object to Activity A

How do I accomplish this? And in which method do I read in the passed object in Activity A?

Comment: want to pass which type of object ? integer, float, string ?

Comment: I have an object that is serializable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can start your intent using `startActivityForResult` on Activity A ... And when finishing Activity B declare a bundle and put your serializable object to your bundle and add it to your intent. On Activity A's `onActivityResult` method you can get this intent back and retrieve your bundle...

Refer to this sample below.

http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577

Comment: I have an interesting problem. I have an Activity that calls a Search Manager which directs me to Activity B. I want to pass some data from B to A at this point. onActivityResult never gets called in Activity A.

Comment: See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597919/how-to-handle-callback-from-search-manager

Answer (score 1):

Intents are used to send data between 2 activities....If its serializable data than send it using:
Eg:
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(home.this,dvd.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(name, value);