# Get result from SearchManager activity to Main Activity in android

Tags: android, callback, android-activity

Use Case:
Activity A is main activity. Whereas Activity B is SearcActivity (SearchManager). Activity B is ListActivity, so whatever result comes, result is displayed in the list. Once user clicks on the list, I want to get that list selected item to be returned to ActivityA.

What I did?
I could call SearchActivity on button using "onSearchRequested()". In ActivityB, I am displaying searchresult via "setListAdapter(adapter)". Using "onListItemClick", I can get what option in list was selected by user.

Now I tried sending result back to ActivityA by following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("item", l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent() );
finish();
```

And in ActivityA, I tried reading the result in "onActivityResult".

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
String strItem = bundle.getString("item");
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Item Selected");
alertDialog.setMessage("Item = " + strItem);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  return;
 }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

Problem:
I noticed that, once Activity A is resumed, "onActivityResult" is not called at all. Hence I am not seeing any dialog. Plus I can't verify whether SearchActivity actually sends anything to ActivityA.

So friends, how can I capture the data sent by ActivityB.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a duplicate to [How to handle callback from Search Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597919/how-to-handle-callback-from-search-manager/5968730).

Mario Lenci is right that your Activity B is not started with `startActivityForResult` when calling `onSearchRequested()`.

See [my answer to that question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597919/how-to-handle-callback-from-search-manager/5968730#5968730).  Essentially you can instead make Activity A your searchable activity to get the query and manually launch Activity B for a result.

Answer (score 1):

Is it you probably wanted to write:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent );
```

instead of

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent() );
```

see the function call?